Why adding a FileProvider via AndroidManifest.xml prevents my app from running?
This is my first time asking a question on stack overflow, let me know if I missed mandatory informations.
I'll try to summarize efficiently.
The goal
I'm coding a Unity Android App, in which I want to implement an auto-update functionnality.
After Unity has downloaded the updated version of my app from a server, I want it to open it programmaticaly.
On Unity side, everything works fine (I can call custom made java functions from my *.aar file).
On Android Studio side (which I'm using for the first time), I'm implementing a "OpenApk()" method.
My code
Here is what I import to use Android tools:
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import java.io.File;

Here is my function in Android Studio:
public void openApkFile(String _filePath) {
    try {
        File apkFullPath = new File(context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + _filePath);
        Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", apkFullPath);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        printToastMessage(e.toString(), true);
    }
}

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.opu.intranet"> <!-- I ADDED MY PACKAGE NAME HERE -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />

    <!-- ADDING THIS PROVIDER VIA XML PREVENTS APP FROM RUNNING (CRASH ON EXECUTION) -->
    <application>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>

Also I added:
android.useAndroidX=true # WAS ALREADY PRESENT BY DEFAULT
android.enableJetifier=true

to gradle.properties.
Le problem
Whenever I build my *.aar package and add it to Unity, if the AndroidManifest.xml file contains , the app won't run anymore on my phone.
It closes immediately after opening, and the OS asks me to wait for the developer to solve the problem haha.
[EDIT]: Thanks to "Retire Ninja"'s comment, I discovered "logcat"...
Here is the error log:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.opu.securityconcilapp, PID: 29513
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.core.content.FileProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.content.FileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~jLNBDfF2HmsctyymOxViwQ==/com.opu.securityconcilapp-bZsahkZ0i3R7T1ZoK0sdTw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~jLNBDfF2HmsctyymOxViwQ==/com.opu.securityconcilapp-bZsahkZ0i3R7T1ZoK0sdTw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~jLNBDfF2HmsctyymOxViwQ==/com.opu.securityconcilapp-bZsahkZ0i3R7T1ZoK0sdTw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:8463)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:7963)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7649)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2478)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8893)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:608)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.content.FileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~jLNBDfF2HmsctyymOxViwQ==/com.opu.securityconcilapp-bZsahkZ0i3R7T1ZoK0sdTw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~jLNBDfF2HmsctyymOxViwQ==/com.opu.securityconcilapp-bZsahkZ0i3R7T1ZoK0sdTw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~jLNBDfF2HmsctyymOxViwQ==/com.opu.securityconcilapp-bZsahkZ0i3R7T1ZoK0sdTw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateProvider(AppComponentFactory.java:147)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:8447)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:7963) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7649) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2478) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8893) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:608) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103) 

Software versions
Unity: 2022.3.20f1
Android Studio: 2023.2.1
Gradle: 7.1.2 on Unity side, 8.4 on Android Studio side
Android: 14 (API 34)
Target SDK : API 24 or higher
Fix attempts
I spent 2 days reading similar discussions about this everywhere, and testing multiple combinations. I even unzipped AndroidFileOpener (See here) by Mihail5412, a plugin I used before but stopped working after a while (Unity Editor package rename errors).
I tried removing "enableJetifier=true", using "android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" instead of "androidx.core.content.FileProvider" (with the required *.jar library added to the project but it created duplicates with androidx.core).
A huge thanks to anyone who will take the time to read me, please be sure I'll follow that thread with attention.
Best regards.

Somehow the first sentence "Hi everyone" won't stay on the post... So please be assured I said "Hi!" haha

You're saying adb logcat doesn't work to see the logs? Is your device set to allow usb debugging and the connection allowed on the device?

I didn't know about logcat (shows how little I know about Android devices yet), I figured out how to filter my package log out of it. I add it to the post and start to dive into it, thanks a lot!

Looks like you're missing a dependency to androidx.core. You should add it to your custom gradle template or via a dependencies xml file in your project so the resolver knows to copy it in. https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver

I fixed the problem, a huge thanks to Bob Smith, Retired Ninja for their help here, and to Tomas1856 member of Unity Dev team on this thread.
I have to add:
-keep class androidx.core.content.FileProvider { *; }
to proguard-user.txt, file to enable via Unity->Edit->Projects Settings->Player->Publishing Settings->Custom Proguard File.
The file path is then showed by Unity below the toggle button.
I also had to add:
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

to gradleTemplate.properties, file to enable via Unity->Edit->Projects Settings->Player->Publishing Settings->Custom Gradle Properties Template.
Final Android Studio AndroidManifest.xml configuration is:
<application>
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
</application>

I still have issues with file path configuration to allow the plugin to open the APK (Failed to find configured root that contains [...]), but I'll ask a new question for that, since it is off topic.

Ah Proguard, the hero and villain of so many stories. Haven't had to fight with it for a while. Glad you figured it out!

Try this solution:

Add

src/main/res/xml/file_paths.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path name="images" path="Pictures" />
</paths>


Add

src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
<provider
    android:name="com.image.crop.lib.DocumentScannerFileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.image.crop.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
  <meta-data
      android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
      android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>


Add

src/main/java/com/image/crop/lib/DocumentScannerFileProvider.kt
package com.image.crop.lib

import androidx.core.content.FileProvider

class DocumentScannerFileProvider : FileProvider() {}



How to use

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File apkFullPath = new File(context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + _filePath);
apkFullPath = photoFile.absolutePath
val apkUri: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
    activity, "com.image.crop.provider", apkFullPath
)
intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, apkUri)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

context.startActivity(intent);


Hi Bob, thanks for your suggestion. My understanding is that you suggest to make my own CustomFileProvider class extending "androidx.core.content.FileProvider", which I did try before.
This throws "Unable to get provider com.opu.intranet.CustomFileProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException".
If you are suggesting to use the actual "com.image.crop" library to go around the problem, can you link me to it please?
I can't find it. Thanks again!

I am not suggesting to use any library com.image.crop this is the package name of my class you change it as per your package name.

Alright that's what I understood first, thanks. Sadly it doesn't work, I wonder if it may not just be an issue with Unity settings, unable to find androidx.core, I'll also ask on Unity forums.

@Stericraft check this https://forum.unity.com/threads/crash-at-app-startup-fatal-exception-main.726650/
